# Unable to Start MySql (8.0.15) on OS-X High Sierra (10.13.6) PID File

Tags: mysql, macos

Starting on PHP/MySQL Development and as the title states, downloaded MySQL 8.0.15 DMG. Installed. However, when I attempt to run the terminal command:
`"sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server.start"`

I get:

`"Starting MysQl .......... "`

which finally ends in:

`ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Macbook.hsd.comcast.net.pid)`

So far I have tried:

- Tried to remove the "Macbook.hsd.comcast.net.pid" file located in the data directory but all i keep getting a "`No Such file or directory`"
- To look for default "my.cnf" file to mod or to add the default values, HOWEVER I read that: "By default the OS X installation does not use a my.cnf, and My SQL just uses the default values. To set up your own my.cnf, you could just create a file straight in /etc.
- An "auto.cnf" exists in the data folder, i'm not sure if MySQL uses that or would respect a "my.cnf" created in the `/usr/local/sql/data/` folder.
- I'm not sure of the proper location to create a "my.cnf" (see, all I want to do is set the proper value for the "pid-file" such as `pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid` and then create the directory and give it the proper permissions. SEE UPDATE AT BOTTOM:
- <strike>I'm cannot access the "data" folder in MySQL folder (which is alias of): "`/usr/local/mysql-8.0.15-macos10.14-x86_64/`". It keeps telling me I don't have permission. There is a little red dot</strike>
- I have set checked the permissions in "`/user/local/mysql/`" and did a

"`sudo chown -RL root:mysql /user/local/mysql`"

"`sudo chown -RL _mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data`"
In the /mysql/ directory now everything reads:
[image]

Stumped and not sure where to move on from here.

Is the fact that I can't access the data folder a result because I haven't made one/specified one? Can't seem to find an answer for getting MySQL working with HighSierra/Mojave. I can't believe that it's just dead.

I would appreciate any/all help.

**UPDATE/EDIT:**

- Was able to add my user permissions to the "`/user/local/mysql/data`" folder and was finally able to access the error file ("Macbook.hsd.comcast.net.err") and a "auto.cnf".
- The "auto.cnf" file is empty besides a single line: `[auto] server-uuid=e7986494-331d-11e9-9691-bec9b3249da6` (not sure if I need to modify the auto.cnf and add PID entries). See error BELOW which seems to indicate otherwise.
- The Error file had repeated Errors (occurred several Times):
  [image]